# How to use array list from database on another method using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

i have an array list which is initialized by using retrofit 2 method , and i want to use that array list on another method, how to do that ?
i have tried to initiate array variable outside the retrofit 2 method and then recall it + initiate its length in retrofit 2 method and also trying to use static variable nothing works

array = yAxisData

code retrofit 2 method

```
 public void getIPList(String UserId){
        Call<IpListResponse> getIPList = mApiService.getIPList(
                UserId
        );
        getIPList.enqueue(new Callback<IpListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<IpListResponse> call, Response<IpListResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<IpList> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list = response.body().getIpList();
                    yAxisData = new double[list.size()];
                    for (int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
                        yAxisData[i] = Double.valueOf(list.get(i).getIp());
                    }
                    Log.d("TESTER", String.valueOf(yAxisData.length));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<IpListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
```

method where i want to use array

```
 public void setGrafik1(){
        String[] axisData = {" ","I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII"};
        List yAxisValues = new ArrayList();
        List axisValues = new ArrayList();
        Line line = new Line(yAxisValues);
        for(int i = 0; i < yAxisData.length; i++){
            axisValues.add(i, new AxisValue(i).setLabel(axisData[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < yAxisData.length; i++){
            yAxisValues.add(new PointValue(i, (float) yAxisData[i]));
        }
       .....
       .....
    }
```

Comment: Is this setGrafik1() function in the same class ?

Comment: @HagarMagdy yes same class

Comment: Why don't you simply pass this array to setGrafik1 function?

Comment: @HagarMagdy somehow the chart is crashes when i call inside retrofit method, but ive managed to solved this by changing hellochart into mikephil chart

Comment: Try my solution and if it crashed with you just show me the crash

Comment: @HagarMagdy sorry i alrd have changed the code so much, but as i remember the crashes is not about value crash it's about fail drawing the activity or something, anyway thanks for replying i appreciate it